# "The "remote_path" setting is not specified

Tags: sublimetext3

I've spent the last 3 days looking for the solution here. I've spent the last 3 days reading Sublime SFTP documentation repeatedly. When I try to access the remote server, it throws up error messages that say, 'The "remote_path" setting is not specified...'

I can't connect to the remote server. I've been over the remote path settings with the host.

Can someone PLEASE help me? Please forgive me if I haven't done anything right here. God knows I've tried.

[image: Link to error messages]

Comment: Can you also add to your answer the contents of the file that the error message is referring to?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand.

Comment: I meant edit the question to include the contents of `/Users/TrixieMacMin/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/sftp_servers/maxperformance-old.sublime-workspace` (for example) so we could see if there was any problem, but if you already solved your problem that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I eventually figured out that I needed to UNCOMMENT my password. Simple as that. Derp.